# Accept a pdf page drop into a C# windows form application

Tags: c#, pdf, drag-and-drop

I am trying to allow users to drag a page from a PDF pages tab into a C# listbox control.  The only information I need from acrobat is the file name of the document they are dragging from and the page number/numbers they have dragged over.  I tried finding out this information from the debugger(add a break point at my dragenter event handler then look at the dragEventArgs).  From that I see a Forms.DataObject but that seems to have no public properties.

My questions:

Does the DataObject hold the PDF file name and the selected pages that are being draged over?

Is this information accessible?

If it is not accessible this way is there a work around?

Thanks for any help you can share.

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted this question on the adobe site and they say that this functionality is not supported by their documentation.  Guess I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The information in the DataObject totally depends on the source of the dragdrop operation. WHat app/ control is the source of the dragdrop? Does it put the information you are looking for when the dragdrop starts?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat is the source of the DataObject.  I believe the information is in there I just need to use the proper IDataFormat class to get the information from e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.THISISWHATINEED,false)

Answer (score 0):

See https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1688371?q=drag%20page . Looks like someone made some progress but either didn't share the outcome or gave up. I suspect the latter.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)